# Laravel: defining relationship based on where value falls in a range?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, range

I am working on an application where an Item has a value called wavelength. In another table, represented by the model Color, there are many entries in the form of {id | color | start_wavelength | end_wavelength}. I am trying to figure out how to define a relationship in the Item Model that can get the Color based on where it falls in the range.

Essentially what I am needing is to get the color where the start_wavelength is greater or equal to the value of the item's wavelength AND where the end_wavelength value is less than that of the item's wavelength.

This is what I am trying to do currently but it obviously work work because the relationship isn't defined by Primary Keys and Foreign Keys.

```
public function color()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Color')->where('wavelength', '<=', 'end')->where('wavelength', '>=', 'start');
}
```

Is there a better way to do this or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a defined relationship between Item and Color you won't be able to use the belongsTo method. Instead, just query for the first Color which matches your criteria and return that

```
return Color::where('wavelength', '<=', 'end')->where('wavelength', '>=', 'start')->firstOrFail();
```

Or better yet:

```
return Color::whereBetween('wavelength', ['start', 'end'])->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Okay so unless I define a relationship using primary and foreign keys, I shouldn't be using the blongsTo/hasOne/etc.. methods?

Comment: @kyle Correct, unless a table specifies a foreign relationship with another table or you have a pivot table established between the two, you won't be able to use Eloquent's relationship methods.